# Search plugin form on "Add Plugin" page not working

Tags: wp-admin, search

Search plugin form not working.

Steps to produce: admin-> plugin-> Add New.

This is used to search plugin but this form is not submitting.

Wordpress Version 4.1.1

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please check the console for any errors and post those. It's difficult to debug without more info.

Comment: Its very old issue and not looking in error log. please guide me how to regenerate it ?

Answer (score 0):

is this a localhost install of wordpress?

i had this problem with a localhost install, and it ended up being read/write permission issues between my /var/html/ folder and WP itself, and then it was read/write issues with the database :/

after working on it for a long time, i finally gave up and followed a different tutorial for installing LAMP/WP in one long step. and that fixed it.

if running WP on a VM for developement, first check to make sure your VM has network access. that occasionally breaks my localhost install.

good luck!

Comment: This is live site and i setup same on local (window+ xampp) but issue remain same. and what is VM ?